# MongoDB 3.2 and Ubuntu 14 - Config file modification

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04, config, nosql

I'm new with mongodb, and now i'm trying anable authorization:enabled and after change the config file i can't connect to mongo.

I done those steps:

1- Change the DB folder location on the mongod.config
   (after that, mongo works ok)

2- Follow the security tutorial:  [mongodb Security CheckList](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

a- Add user administration using the tutorial

b- Stop mongo service

b- change my config file:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

security:
        authorization : "enabled"
```

The dbPath, has mongodb permission (that is not the problem, see point 1)

c- Start mongo service

d- When i try to connect to mongo, i see this error:

```
julio@casa1:~$ mongo -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: test
2016-11-06T21:06:44.751+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-11-06T21:06:44.761+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I don't know what is wrong on mongoDB tutorial.

Can any body help me ?

Thanks

This is my actual log:

```
2016-11-06T19:27:45.689+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /usr/local/var/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger$
2016-11-06T19:27:45.690+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=$
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-11-06T19:27:46.144+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-11-06T19:27:46.148+0100 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/usr/loca$
2016-11-06T19:27:46.149+0100 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-11-06T19:27:46.150+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-11-06T19:29:55.766+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60124 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-11-06T19:29:59.748+0100 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:60124 (0 connections now open)
2016-11-06T19:40:13.939+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60126 #2 (1 connection now open)
2016-11-06T19:40:15.606+0100 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:60126 (0 connections now open)
2016-11-06T19:40:18.425+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60128 #3 (1 connection now open)
2016-11-06T19:41:29.422+0100 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:60128 (0 connections now open)
2016-11-06T19:41:45.468+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd en$
2016-11-06T19:41:45.468+0100 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2016-11-06T19:41:45.469+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2016-11-06T19:41:45.469+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-11-06T19:41:45.469+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2016-11-06T19:41:45.469+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2016-11-06T19:41:45.470+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2016-11-06T19:41:45.470+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-11-06T19:41:45.470+0100 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-11-06T19:41:45.470+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2016-11-06T19:41:45.545+0100 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-11-06T19:41:45.545+0100 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
```

Comment: What does the log file `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` say?

Comment: i will update my question with a part of my log. Can your help me . Thanks

Comment: It's not obvious what is sending the sig term. It may be your startup script try to run mongod strait from shell: `mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf` to see if it works fine. Also `authorization : "enabled"` is suspicious. Do you have `Tab` key in front? In that case replace it with spaces.

Comment: Hello, about the config file, the authorization : "enabled", i dont use any tab key there. Another question: ¿why use --fork --config ?. Why Ubuntu doesn't get the changes over the config file ... ?

when I use `mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf` it doesn't do anthyng, i continue with the same error, i can't connect to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1- modify the config file. The security part must be on this form:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

2- continue with the mongodb turorial

After this all works with an authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late. But it might help someone.
I got stuck in the same problem.

The string should not contain the quotes.

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Please mind the space as well. Caused me trouble. Be sure of not putting tabs.
Hope this helps